# How can I access to the API response data through models (parent and child classes)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to access to the API response data but it shows null when i am trying to access the data using the models. How can access to all the response data using the models?

Here are what I have done so far:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var res = json.decode(response.body);
  print("Ress...$res"); //PRINTS THE MAPPED DATA
  Gate gate = new Gate.fromJson(res);
  print(gate.a.b); // PRINTS NULL
```

The above code returns null. How can I access to the data? Can i access all(the parent and child data) through parent?

**Edited**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Gate {
  @JsonKey(name: "A")
  A a;

  Gate(this.a);
  factory Gate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  _$GateFromJson(json);
}
```

**class A**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class A {
  @JsonKey(name: "B")
  B b;
  @JsonKey(name: "C")
  C c;

  A(this.b,this.c);

  factory A.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AFromJson(json);
}
```

**class B**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class B {
   @JsonKey(name: "D")
   List<D> listOfD;
   B(this.listOfD);

   factory B.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BFromJson(json);
}
```

**Class C**

```
  @JsonSerializable()
  class C {
   @JsonKey(name: "productID")
   double productId;
   C(this.productId);

   factory C.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CFromJson(json);
 }
```

**Class D**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class D {
   @JsonKey(name: "Name")
   String name;
   D(this.name);

  factory D.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$DFromJson(json);
```

}

**Here is the json data**

```
{
"A": {
    "B": [
        {
            "Name": "name1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "name2"
        },
        {
            "Name": "name3"
        }
    ],
    "C": {
        "productID": 111.2
    }
}}
```

I have created `x.g.dart` automatically based on the above models. It still returns null

Comment: Which data you use?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Give an example of your data here. Need sample data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Now everything looks like this. You say - help me, I'm freezing in Africa. You are asked - in what conditions? You answer - I am in normal conditions, I sit in my underwear in the refrigerator.

Comment: I have updated the question